# H3Index in which Hexagon?

Tags: javascript, h3

Actually I'm playing with the uber h3-Api in JavaScript. I've split the area into a few hexagons. 
By given the **hexeid** into the **kRing** function.

Now I want to know by a given lat/lng in which Hexagon (ID) the lat/lng is. I know that I have to transform the lat/lng into the hexId. Ok done..but how do i know in which hexagon it is?

Im using this JS-Api
https://github.com/uber/h3-js

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know what k-ring the a given H3 index is in (k-rings are roughly hexagonal in shape, but “hexagon” usually refers to an H3 index).

H3 doesn’t offer any specific functions for this. The general approach is to iterate through the indexes in the k-ring and make an `{index: kRing}` map. Then when you get the H3 index for a specific lat/lng, you can look it up in the map to get the associated k-ring.